# Skip certain array items on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object, fetch

I'm very new to React and coding. I'm fetching data from data from API, I manage to fetch all the data with a map function, so now I have all the data. I put the mapping function below.
But what I would like to do is to select the data and not have them all printed, for instance I would like to have just the ERNERC KCAL and FAT and I'm lost I don't how do that. I attached a picture of the data. All the help will be really appreciated

```js
   {Object.keys(nutritions).map(key => (<Nutrition
        label={nutritions[key].label}
        quantity={nutritions[key].quantity}
        unit={nutritions[key].unit}
        
        />))}
```

[image: object]

Comment: You want to pass all properties of the object to the `Nutrition` component?

Comment: I already pass all the properties of the object to the Nutrition component and it's working fine but now  I just want to display 2 of them and I don't know how to do that

Comment: So you only want to display two objects of your response in a Nutrition component?

Comment: you can just add an IF statement inside of the map. if(item.label === 'FAT') { // do something}

Comment: yes exactly like ENERC_KAL and FAT. I 've tried to put the key itself but it's not working

Comment: Just add an if statement(ternary) where you check for those two. `key === ‘xxx’ || key === ‘yyy’ ? <Nutrition> : null

Comment: @ffffff01 is right. I thought of similar solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may conditionally skip certain items while doing `.map()`, e.g. like this:

```
{
    Object.keys(nutritions).map(key => 
        ['ENERC_KCAL', 'FAT'].includes(key) && 
        (
            <Nutrition
                label={nutritions[key].label}
                quantity={nutritions[key].quantity}
                unit={nutritions[key].unit}
            />
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: ah great that's what I tried to do but I didn't put the key in an array and  I also put them after the includes. It works. Thanks a lot

Comment: can you please why you put the &&  after includes(key)

Comment: That's called [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) and is, basically equivalent to `if(['ENERC_KCAL', 'FAT'].includes(key)){return <Nutrition...`

Answer (score 1):

With short circuit evaluation:

```js
{Object.keys(nutritions).map(key => key === "YOUR_VAL" && (<Nutrition
        label={nutritions[key].label}
        quantity={nutritions[key].quantity}
        unit={nutritions[key].unit}

        />))}
```

With if statements:

```js
{Object.keys(nutritions).map(key =>{

 if (key === "YOUR_VAL") return (<Nutrition
        label={nutritions[key].label}
        quantity={nutritions[key].quantity}
        unit={nutritions[key].unit}

        />)})}
```

With filter

```js
const myKeys = ["VAL1", "VAL2"]

{Object.keys(nutritions)
.filter((key) =>  myKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1)
.map(key => (<Nutrition
        label={nutritions[key].label}
        quantity={nutritions[key].quantity}
        unit={nutritions[key].unit}

        />))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input; fixed it